# Erase Activities from Stack

Tags: android, stack, android-activity

I there, I already read some questions about this, but none helped me, because what I want to do is lightly different.

I have this activities, example:

A->B->C->D->E

On D I have a button to move to E, and when I enter activity E, I want to erase all the activities between A and E.
So if I press the back button at E, I will go back to activity A.

I know ! I could do this overriding the method onKeyDown... and just move the user to the activity A, but the whole activities would keep in the stack, I want to erase them!
For performance and for better management, I just dont need them anymore, understand?

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: When in B, C or D if the user back press do you want to go back to the previous activity?

Comment: Yes I want, thats why I cannot use the android:noHistory="true" tag

Comment: Do you start E from D with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag? If so why does that work is beyond me. What API is your minimum target?

Comment: Nope I don't, I start E normally.. and then if user press key back I start A with that flag. thats what I am doing now, as Stan suggested . The minimum target I am using is API 8 , why ?

Comment: You start A on Back press so this is ok. If you min API is 11 you can use another flag. You can also clear the stack when D start E but that involves more codes.

Comment: Yes ! That was what I was looking for when I started the question, but then I remembered, that I could just start A pressing back key on E, and handle that new activity using the flag that clears everything on top . But thanks ! If it involves more code, I will keep this last approach :)

Comment: Ok, if you send any new intent back then you should override onNewIntent to catch the intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a special intent flag (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) while just starting the needed activity.

Comment: Not really :) It could cause a long wait at start of target activity which depends on amount of activities to clear. Your activities maybe lightweight as for now and maybe you use also some powerful device so you didn't notice the pause.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, So which is a better solution ?

Comment: its up 2u :) No history is not an option as 4me cuz then user can't return to previous activity using back button but u might want him to return to it or not which depends on some circumstances. It this situation FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is the only way.

Comment: Yes you are right, depends on the situation, kay thanks stan ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest you can write

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:noHistory="true">
```

For each activity that you want off the stack.